# The plane minus the graph of a continuous function consists of two path-connected components?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be continuous. Show that $\Bbb R^2-\mathrm{graph}(f)$ consists of two path-connected components.

I can show that the area 'above' the graph of $f$ and the area 'below' the graph of $f$ are path-connected, but I'm having difficulty showing these exhaust the path-connected components and are also distinct components.

I think I can use the Jordan Curve Theorem (on the sphere) to complete this, but I'm having difficulty formalizing the argument. I want to add a point at infinity to create $S^2$ and extend the graph of $f$ to include this new point. Then this new graph would correspond to a continuous image of $S^1$ in $S^2$ and separate $S^2$ into two path-connected components.

Any help in completing my argument, or supplementing your own proof of the claim, is appreciated.

Comment: Every point in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \text{graph}(f)$ is in one of the two components, no?

Comment: @Travis: I think the point is that we do not know that there is actually more than one component.

Comment: @Travis I should have stated that I also want to show they are distinct. I've added that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any path $\varphi$ connecting a point below the graph to a point above the graph. Consider the map

$$
t \mapsto f(\varphi_1 (t)) - \varphi_2 (t),
$$

where $\varphi_i$ are the components of $\varphi$.

Why does this help you?

Comment: What exactly are the functions $\varphi_i$?

Comment: $\varphi(t) = (\varphi_1 (t), \varphi_2 (t))$. And $\varphi$ is a path connecting a point "below" the graph to a point "above".

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. I'm still interested in seeing in other proofs, but I'll most likely accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious candidates for the path components are the sets
$$R_+ := \{(x, y) : y > f(x)\} \qquad\text{and} \qquad R_- := \{(x, y) : y < f(x)\}.$$
Both of these are open in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \text{graph}(f)$ (in the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}^2$) because they are open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and each is the complement of the other in $\mathbb{R}^2 - \text{graph}(f)$, so both are closed. In particular, the sets $R_{\pm}$, which you've shown are path-connected, belong to different components, and hence to different path components.

By construction $R_+ \cup R_- = \mathbb{R}^2 - \text{graph}(f)$, so these exhaust the path components of the space.

Comment: Is it clear that $R_\pm$ are both open? This is the one part of your argument I don't see immediately. (I think you mean $\Bbb R^2-\mathrm{graph}(f)$ as well)

Comment: Yes, they're both open in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and so they're open in the subspace topology on $\mathbb{R}^2 - \text{graph}(f)$.

Comment: That's what I was asking. Is it clear they're open in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: (And you're right, thank you.)

Comment: Yes: $R_+$ is the preimage of the open set $(0, \infty)$ under the continuous map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $(x, y) \mapsto y - f(x)$, so it is open by definition of continuity, and similarly for $R_-$.